# ListArray Saving Same records

Tags: java, mysql, sql, list

I am trying to save my Database Table in a **ListArray** of a Class **Students**.

```
public List<Students> getData() {
    //_Students.clear();
    Students tempStudent = new Students();
    List<Students> students = new ArrayList<>();
    dbConnect();
    try {
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Students;");
        int size = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            tempStudent.studentId = rs.getInt("StudentNo");
            tempStudent.studentName = rs.getString("StudentName");
            tempStudent.studentAge = rs.getInt("StudentAge");
            students.add(tempStudent);
            size++;
        }
        rs.close();
        c.commit();
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return students;
}
```

In while loop when i try to print data as

```
   System.out.println("Student Id: " + tempStudent.studentId);
```

it prints perfectly fine. But when i try to print it as

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.println("Student Id: " + student.get(i).studentId);
    }
```

It prints the last record that was read from Database. Number of records is same. If there are 4 rows saved in Database table then the record that is displayed will also be 4 times.

Is there something wrong with the way i am using LIST?
Thanks!

Comment: Create a new instance of `tempStudent` a the beginning of your while. You are overwriting the value.

Comment: @Muneeb, don't say sorry, this stack over flow. Look at my update. it will clear your doubt as following A.jsp> conntroller.java > dao.java>dbUtil.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Students tempStudent = new Students();
```

change it to

```
Students tempStudent;
```

You are `overridding` the `property of same object` since you created the `tempStudent` `outside` the `while loop`. You have to add the `objects` equal to the `number of record` in the database. So create the `tempStudent object` as below.

use

```
while (rs.next()) {
        tempStudent = new Students();
        tempStudent.studentId = rs.getInt("StudentNo");
        tempStudent.studentName = rs.getString("StudentName");
        tempStudent.studentAge = rs.getInt("StudentAge");
        students.add(tempStudent);
        size++;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a new Object in every iteration that will resolve your problem.

```
tempStudent = new Students();
tempStudent.studentId = rs.getInt("StudentNo");
tempStudent.studentName = rs.getString("StudentName");
tempStudent.studentAge = rs.getInt("StudentAge");
students.add(tempStudent);
size++;
```

Comment: Because you are iterating and assign the values into the object then add it into the list. But you use the same object. So only the list contains same value. Create it as new object every time. It resolves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create new object of  class Student inside the while loop like

```
while (rs.next()) {

            tempStudent = new Students();
            tempStudent.studentId = rs.getInt("StudentNo");
            tempStudent.studentName = rs.getString("StudentName");
            tempStudent.studentAge = rs.getInt("StudentAge");
            students.add(tempStudent);
            size++;
        }
```

The issue was only single object was created and in every iteration attributes of same object is updated and add in the list due to which last updated attributes is viewed in the list i.e. last record of the row.

Answer (score 1):

you are using the same instance of tempStudent. So each element of the ArrayList is pointing to the same Students object. Create before everytime you are inserting into the list.

Comment: oh so this is exactly like linked lists, an object pointing to same memory? Explains everything!

Answer (score 1):

i guess when you make a  object as Students
it may like follow :

```
  public class Students {

    private int StudentId = 0;
    private String StudentName = "defaultName";
    private int StudentAge = 18;

    public int getStudentId() {
        return StudentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        StudentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getStudentName() {
        return StudentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        StudentName = studentName;
    }
    public int getStudentAge() {
        return StudentAge;
    }
    public void setStudentAge(int studentAge) {
        StudentAge = studentAge;
    }
}
```

maybe you will find something wrong on your object student!

Comment: I had thought about putting getters and setters. As this is not exactly what i'll be doing. This is just an example for learning. What exactly i want to do is searate thing and I will surely put getters/setters in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another one interesting answer is following as:

```
public List<User> getAllUsers()
    {
        List<User> users=new ArrayList<User>();
    try
    {
            Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("Select * from Students");

            while(rs.next())
            {
                User user=new User();
                user.setUserid(rs.getInt(("StudentNo");));
                user.setFirstName(rs.getString("StudentName"));
                user.setLastName(rs.getString("StudentAge"));
                users.add(user);
            }
     }
    catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return users;
    }
```

---

the User will be reference from this format. And just look at the simple format are following as:

```
   A.jsp> conntroller.java > dao.java>dbUtil.java
```

---

**how to work this User as following as:**

The jsp is a front page**(A.jsp)**.  If you want doing some operation like **delete, update, add or anything else** your going to create the reference operation in th java program. 
In that java page should be in the particular controller operation (EX. update). we should using the User(reference from the page).

**A.jsp(user call)**

```
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" 
            value="<c:out value="${user.firstName}"/>"/><br/>
```

**Controller.java**

```
public UserController() 
{
dao = new UserDao();
}
{
//controller operation like update;
}
```

**Dao.java**

```
public class UserDao 
{
private Connection connection;
public UserDao()
{
connection=DbUtil.getConnection();
}
public void updateUser(User user)
{
//update operation, and here only using the user 
}
```

**DbUtil.java**

```
public class DbUtil 
{
public static Connection con = null;
public static Connection getConnection()
{ 
//db connection 
}
}
```

Comment: What is User? is it a Predefined Class or just as a reference to the class i am using? and yes it is good. but the method that i used increases the looks and feels OF A CODE. Thanks!

Comment: @Muneeb, they User is reference list page like, List<User> users=new ArrayList<User>();

Comment: I easily understand what you are trying to teach me. But what i am saying is the LOOK of a code is better if EQUALS signs '=' are used and stuff.

Comment: A.jsp> conntroller.java > dao.java>dbUtil.java ---
i didnt understand this. sorry!

Comment: @Muneeb, don't say sorry, this stack over flow. Look at my update. it will clear your doubt as following A.jsp> conntroller.java > dao.java>dbUtil.java