# Resource not found error while trying to deliver a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working with resteasy with war file deployed on jboss (6.0.2 EAP)

I have the following workflow :

1. URL hit calls a `servlet(doGet() method)`
2. this servlet is supposed to deliver a jsp page to the client

   JSP page resides in `WebContent/customFolder`

   I use the `requestDispatcher().forward()` method to invoke the JSP

   The path given in `forward("/customFolder/name_of_jsp")`
3. the jsp has a form, whose action attribute points to another servlet

the problem is , once the `forward()` method is called, the browser returns a 404 resource not found error.

I have followed some questions already posted on this forum and was not able to solve this issue.

Can anyone please guide me.

Edit:
JSP page :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="javax.servlet.*,java.lang.String"%>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Password Reset Page</title>

</head>
<body>
<form method="GET" action="Resteasy">
<%!String userId;%>
<%userId = (String)getServletContext().getAttribute("userid"); %>
<p>User Id:<%= userId %></p>
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pass">
<br>
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="rePwd" id ="c_pass" onblur="confirmPass()"><br>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmPass() {
        var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value
        var confPass = document.getElementById("c_pass").value
        if(pass != confPass) {
            alert('Wrong confirm password !');
            document.getElementById("c_pass").focus();
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

The servlet which has to deliver the jsp :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        log.info("Received request for popup jsp page");

        String userId = request.getParameter("userid");
        String utc = request.getParameter("utc");

        log.info("Recieved userid = "+ userId);
        log.info("Received utc is = "+ utc);


        ServletContext requestContext = request.getServletContext();
        requestContext.setAttribute("userid", userId);
        requestContext.setAttribute("UTC", utc);


        String htmlfileName = null; 


        try {

            htmlfileName =   new DeltaPropertyHandler(
                    DeltaConstants.LINK_HTML_FILE).getPropertyValue(DeltaConstants
                            .USER_PASSWORD_RESET_HTML);
            File file = new File(requestContext.getRealPath(htmlfileName));
            if(file.exists()){log.debug("file exists!!");}
            else{log.warn("file does mot exist");}

        } catch (Exception e) {

            log.error("failed to present the jsp page " + e.getMessage());
        }
       log.info("File name is "+htmlfileName);

       RequestDispatcher rd = requestContext.getRequestDispatcher(htmlfileName);

       rd.forward(request, response);

    }
```

Comment: Post your code instead of describing it.

Comment: Post the code of the servlet. That's where the problem probably is.

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = requestContext.getRequestDispatcher(htmlfileName);
```

you should change:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = requestContext.getRequestDispatcher(programname.jsp);
```

*if your using the **get method** as following as:*

```
RequestDispatcher view=request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
            view.forward(request, response);
```

*if your using the **post method** like as:*

```
private static String LIST_USER="/listUser.jsp";

        RequestDispatcher view=request.getRequestDispatcher(LIST_USER);
        request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
        view.forward(request, response);
```

User will be reference from this format. And just look at the simple format are following as:

```
  A.jsp> conntroller.java > dao.java>dbUtil.java
```

*you want the reference for that list as following* [***link to click***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22144001/3176028)

Comment: Could you explain why? The parameter passed to dispatcher is the relative  path of jsp right?